# how to translate searchPlaceholder of MaterialTable reactjs using FormattedMessage

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

i want to translate searchPlaceholder of ui MaterialTable in Reactjs

i can translate all like exportTitle,searchTooltip ..., except searchPlaceholder i made the same like other but they didnt working. 
  this the code

```
const localization = {
    pagination: {
        labelDisplayedRows: '{from}-{to}' + <FormattedMessage id="table.of.label" /> + '{count}'
    },
    toolbar: {
        nRowsSelected: '{0}' + <FormattedMessage id="table.row.label" /> + '(s) selected'
            + <FormattedMessage id="table.selected.label" />,
         searchPlaceholder: <FormattedMessage id="table.search.label" />,
        searchTooltip: <FormattedMessage id="table.search.label" />,
        exportTitle: <FormattedMessage id="table.export.label" />,
    },
    header: {
        actions: <FormattedMessage
            id="table.column.actions"
        />
    },
    body: {
        emptyDataSourceMessage: <FormattedMessage id="table.no_records_to_display.label" />,
        filterRow: {
            filterTooltip: <FormattedMessage id="table.filter.label" />
        },
        addTooltip: <FormattedMessage id="table.add.label" />,
        deleteTooltip: <FormattedMessage id="table.column.actions.delete" />,
        editTooltip: <FormattedMessage id="table.column.actions.edit" />,
    },
    grouping: {
        /* placeholder: <FormattedMessage id="table.drag_headers_here_to_display.label" />, */
    }
};
export default localization;
```

Comment: What is the `searchPlaceholder`? where did you get this key from?

Comment: it is `<FormattedMessage id="table.search.label" />`

Comment: Is you question solved ? I did not saw you last message in so chat until now.

Comment: no it not solved i need a solution only for searchPlaceholder  and i cant change all my solution 
the part of localisation is shared for all  tables

Comment: Well, good luck then! my suggest solution is working and it is the only solution that exists at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the docs in the material-table: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/localization

If you want to change the `searchPlaceholder` you should use the following:

```
<MaterialTable
    ...
    localization={{
        ...
        toolbar: {
            searchTooltip: 'This is the placeholder text'
        },
      ...
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not via `FormattedMessage`.

`material-table` are using `@material-ui` components, and for the search part, they are using the `TextField`. The placeholder is meant to be a string.

To solve your issue, you need to format the placeholder before you give it to material table.

Let's say you have an `IntlProvider` in top of your tree and a selected locale.

All you need is:

1. add a custom message in your messages definition with some id
2. Wrap the component that renders your material-table with `injectIntl` HOC from `react-intl`.
3. In material-table localization add `searchPlaceholder: intl.formatMessage({ id: "my.custom.searchBar" })`.

Working code:

```
import { IntlProvider, injectIntl } from "react-intl";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

const enMessages = {
  "my.custom.searchBar": "search here"
};
const frMessages = {
  "my.custom.searchBar": "rechercher"
};

function TableComponent({ intl }) {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={[
        { title: "Adı", field: "name" },
        { title: "Soyadı", field: "surname" },
        { title: "Doğum Yılı", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
        {
          title: "Doğum Yeri",
          field: "birthCity",
          lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" }
        }
      ]}
      data={[
        { name: "Mehmet", surname: "Baran", birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 }
      ]}
      title="Demo Title"
      localization={{
        toolbar: {
          searchPlaceholder: intl.formatMessage({ id: "my.custom.searchBar" })
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}

const LocalizedTable = injectIntl(TableComponent);

export default function App() {
  const [locale, setLocale] = React.useState("en");

  const messages = locale === "en" ? enMessages : frMessages;
  return (
    <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
      <select onChange={e => setLocale(e.target.value)} value={locale}>
        <option value="en">en</option>
        <option value="fr">fr</option>
      </select>
      <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <LocalizedTable />
      </div>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
}
```

Here is a [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-water-813p5)